# Text overlaying with a background color hides the image on Android?

Tags: android, textview, overlay

On Android, I am trying to create a dynamic image viewer that flip images and at the bottom of each image I display some information about the image,1 or 2 lines of text max. I want to give the area that displays the text a unique background color to let it stand up. Everything works fine with the exception of one thing, when I set a color for TextView to let say “Black” I get the entire screen black covering the image image! and not only the TextView area. Please bear in mind that I create everything dynamically as I am doing below:

```
imageFrame = new FrameLayout(this);

Viewer = new ImageView(this);

imageInfo = new TextView(this);
imageInfo.setHeight(imageInfo.getLineHeight()); imageInfo.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
imageInfo.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
imageFrame.addView(Viewer);
imageFrame.addView(imageInfo);
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to set the height and width dynamically as well. My guess is the textview width and height are set to fill_parent.  If that doesn't work try adding the elements to the imageFrame in a different order.

Below is how you need to set the widths dynamically for each textview.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourtextviewname)
ViewGroup.LayoutParams vg1 = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) tv.getLayoutParams();
vg1.width = 100;

tv.setLayoutParams(vg1);
```

Also try making a linear layout the root element inside your frame layout.  Then put the textview and image view in the linear layout.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried setting both width and height, but it seems that the values I provide doesn't accepted. I even tried to change them after I inserted the my object inside the imageFrame without luck.
reversing the insertion will put the image on top of the text and will hide the text

Comment: How are you setting the widths? Try what I added above to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works to some extent by using LinearLayout. But the bizarre is that if I push in the TextView object, followed by ImageView object inside the LinearLayout it shows the image with the text on top. But if I reverse the insertion order I only see the image and the text disappear. Do you have any clue what is causing this?

The only thing I can think of is that when the ImageView gets inside LinearLayout it sets itself to fill_parent, but on the otherwise I through that LinearLayout will handle re-sizing the objects for them all to show correctly.

Comment: I would guess the size of the image is too large.  I would try resizing the image.

Comment: Can you please mark this answer as correct if it helps. I will continue to offer you support to the best of my ability. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use FrameLayout, you need to know that the elements, what are put in, are stacking, one the each other. You need to use LinearLayout, or RelativeLayout, etc. if you don't want to stack them.